# How to change the LossyScale in Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine

**01:How to change the LossyScale in Unity3D.**

When I wanted to use method "Instantiate<>" to instantiate a FX beneath the Player,but somehow the FX is too big for Player,there is not only one Player,each of them are at dirrerent size,I try to make it smaller by using "LocalScale.Set",but this worked for only one Player,so what should I do.
I'd be thankful if anyone can tell me something about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. [`lossyScale`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-lossyScale.html) is **ReadOnly**.

You have to manually calculate the relative scale you need and than set it via [`localScale`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-localScale.html).

---

Or since you instantiate the object you could simply first scale it correctly and than parent it to the Player like

```c#
// without a parent parameter this is instantiated under the Scene root
var newObject = Instantiate(prefab);

// set the position and rotation
newObject.position = thePlayerObject.position;
newObject.rotation = thePlayerObject.rotation;

// set the desired world scale
newObject.transform.localScale = XYZ;

// parent it to the Player keeping the current world scale
newObject.parent = thePlayerObject.transform;
// equals
//newObject.SetParent(thePlayerObject.transform);
```

`transform.parent = XYZ;` equals [`Transform.SetParent(XYZ);`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.SetParent.html) which uses by default `true` as second parameter which means: current world position, rotation and scale should stay.

---

One alternative solution provided [here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-scale-child-object-independent-of-parent.174289/) was unparenting the object, setting it's scale and than parenting it again while keeping the current lossyScale:

```c#
// store current parent
Transform oldParent = transform.parent;

// unparent / move to the Scene root level
transform.parent = null;

// Set desired scale in world scale
transform.localScale = XXX;

// parent to the before stored parent again
// keeping the current world scale
transform.parent = oldParent;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help,the first solution I'v tried but both the parent or the child scale are(1,1,1),yet the FX is still too big for him,I try to adjust the FX's scale in its Transform component like(0.3,0.3,0.3),I wander if there is a way like "gameobject.transfrom.getcomponent<renderer>().bound.size" to definite it exact size,then I can change the both automatically .

Comment: @derHugo - Could you PLEASE help me with this - In Scenekit IOS 

I have non uniform scale in parent  + non uniform scale in CHILD 

I wanted child's world transform  so If I add copy in root it should match the child